# Rails 3 and Controller Instance Variables Inside a Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I just encounter a problem similar to http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/216433

I need to access controller instance variable from helper.

Here is the code I have done, and it's not work.

Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :set_background_type #for action only background setting

  #for controller-wise background setting
  def set_background_type(string)
    @background_type = string
  end
end
```

Helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def background_type
    @background_type || 'default'
  end

end
```

Layout:

```
<body class="<%= background_type %>">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some searching. I got one solution from

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html

and the Controller becomes:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :set_background_type #for action only background setting
  helper_attr :background_type
  attr_accessor :background_type

  #for controller-wise background setting
  def set_background_type(string)
    @background_type = string
  end

  def background_type
    @background_type || 'default'
  end
end
```

and remove the method from ApplicationHelper.
It's work for this scenario, but I'm still curious,

is there a way to access controller instance variable for method in ApplicationHelper?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using erb templates, which I'm guessing you are, then you need to use erb syntax to call the helper method.  Have you tried:

```
<body class="<%= background_type %>">
```

?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in fact I'm using haml, the view example I gave is just to demonstrate the scenario. I'll fix that, thanx.

Comment: Cool.  Glad you got it figured out!